# How to run a program from string?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0

I have path of an application in a string what I want to run. 
For example: `[io.path]::Combine($path, $filename)` it be interpreted as `C:\foo\baa.exe`. I have tried using `&$path` operator but it don't works by using variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had both `& $path` (note the space) and `Invoke-Item $path` work.

Comment: Thanks. It's possible to pass arguments to program?

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
$path = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
&$path
```

should work. Make sure you are setting path correctly. There is no need for a space after the `&`.